# React no me deja acceder a una propiedad

Tags: reactjs, usestate

Holaa, necesito una ayuda
En mi state tengo toda la estructura armada para realizar el llamado a la api y renderear
pero hay una propiedad que es: official-artwork la cual contiene "-" y no me deja acceder para renderear esos datos. Puedo acceder a cualquier propiedad que no tenga "-" sin problemas y la aplicacion anda perfecto.
como puedo solucionarlo para que me permita  acceder a una propiedad con "-".

```
    SyntaxError: ...\pokeapi\pokeapp\src\components\Pokemon.js: Unexpected token, expected "," 

sprites: {
 other: {
  official-artwork: {
  front_default: "",
  },
},
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿la propiedad la estás declarando tu o te viene así de la API?. Si la estás declarando tu, cuando la declares usa `"official-artwork":{
  front_default: ""}` Si lo que quieres es acceder a ella porque te llega así puedes acceder usando `sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default`

Comment: Genial Jaime, ahi lo solucione!! Gracias por tu respuesta, estoy en proceso de aprendisaje jejeje